# Connecting by default to Logitech K810 Bluetooth Keyboard

Tags: keyboard, bluetooth, logitech

I bought a Logitech K810 Bluetooth Keyboard -- and after using [these steps](http://devasive.blogspot.com/2012/11/ubuntu-1204-persistent-bluetooth-pairing.html) to pair with Ubuntu 14.04 -- I want it to connect by default.

On startup the keyboard is not connected, and after logging in (using a USB keyboard) bluetooth is running but the keyboard is still not connected.

This is what I see immediately after logging in and clicking the bluetooth icon in the task bar.
[image]

All I have to do is click connection for everything to work perfectly. The simplicity of this step leads me to believe that there must be a way to set it to connect by default.

Is there perhaps a startup script or an Ubuntu setting I can change to make this happen? I've looked under Keyboard Settings but I haven't found anything.

Any ideas are appreciated!

Comment: Take a look at the /lib/udev/rules.d/97-bluetooth-hid2hci.rules file and if you can figure out your productid, add it in to the Logitec section.

Comment: Is there a similar solution for 15.10?

Comment: (Many years later)...  Watch out for the "Blueman" bluetooth manager. I installed that as an "upgrade" to "Blueberry" in my Mint 20.04. But I couldn't pair my K810 because "Blueman" never displayed the 6-digit passcode I needed to type in. I had to re-install the original "Blueberry" program to be able to complete the pairing process successfully