# Connecting by default to Logitech K810 Bluetooth Keyboard Ubuntu 15.10

Tags: keyboard, bluetooth, 15.10, logitech

Saw this [Thread](https://askubuntu.com/questions/574222/connecting-by-default-to-logitech-k810-bluetooth-keyboard/723992#723992) about logitech k810 connecting deafult to my desktop ubuntu pc, and was wondering if there are any similar solution for 15.10? 
This seemse  to be working on 14.04 only.

> "Take a look at the /lib/udev/rules.d/97-bluetooth-hid2hci.rules file and if you can figure out your productid, add it in to the Logitec section. "

I either have no `/lib/udev/rules.d/97-bluetooth-hid2hci.rules`,or I'm unable to find it to add my productid. 
Also, `hcitool scan` always comes out empty? Don't know why, my keyboard is connected right now, but after every reboot/hibarnation I have to manually connect it to my pc again, and it's beginning to drive me mad.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu, Could you [edit] question and add output of `lsusb` when keyboard is working.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do the same in 15.10 but I have no way to test it.

1. Get vendor & product id's from:

   ```
   lsusb
   ```
2. Then change `/lib/udev/rules.d/97-hid2hci.rules` (It has been renamed as it seems)